# React native facing issue in my rotating animated component

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

I build that component but I'm facing issue that when I rotate it, the circle icon fluctuated little bit and if I rotate it from other place, it changes position. I want it to fixed to place I left it and start it from there again when I rotate it again. Please see the video below to get better understanding. If you know how can I fix that please help.

video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NxbrAcGXhxC2YemuwVq4A5Ex-Q4ZsvD9/view?usp=sharing

```
const Dailer = () => {
  const gradientColors = [colors.PRIMARY, '#68caff', '#a0e0ff'];

  const renderLines = () => {
    const lineViews = [];
    const angleStep = (2 * Math.PI) / 8; // Divide circle into 8 parts

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      const angle = i * angleStep;

      lineViews.push(<View key={i} style={styles(angle).lines} />);
    }

    return lineViews;
  };

  const lastRotation = useSharedValue(0);

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
        const {dx, dy} = gestureState;
        const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        lastRotation.value = angle;
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gestureState) => {
        const {dx, dy} = gestureState;
        const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        console.log('angle: ', angle);
      },
    }),
  ).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    lastRotation.value = withSpring(0);
  }, [lastRotation]);

  const circleStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          rotate: `${lastRotation.value}rad`,
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={gradientColors}
      style={styles().gradientCircle}
      start={{x: 1, y: 1}} // Start from the bottom edge (outer side)
      end={{x: 0, y: 0}} // Gradient ends at the right
      {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      {renderLines()}
      <Animated.View style={[styles().circle, circleStyle]}>
        <Image source={imagePath.POINTER} style={styles().smallCircle} />
      </Animated.View>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};
```

Icon shouldn't fluctuated and it should start from the point I left it no matter from which point I rotate it.